# Python-pandas with large/disordered text files

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large (for my experience level anyway) text file of astrophysical data and I'm trying to get a handle on python/pandas. As a noob to python, it's comin' along slowly. [Here](https://gist.github.com/bodieskate/5589134) is a sample of the text file, it's a 145Mb total file. When I'm trying to read this in pandas I'm getting confused because I don't know what to use `pd.read_table(example.txt)` or `pd.read_csv(example.csv)`. In either case I can't call on a specific column without ipython freaking out, such as [here](https://gist.github.com/bodieskate/5589187). I know I'm doing something absent-minded. Can anyone explain what that might be? I've done this same procedure with smaller files and it works great, but this one seems to be limiting it's output, or just not working at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your columns are separated by varying amounts of whitespace, so you'll need to specify that as the separator.  Try `read_csv(example.csv, sep=r'\s+')`.  `\s+` is the regular expression for "any amount of whitespace".  Also, you should remove that `#` character from the beginning of the first line, as that will be read as an extra column and will mess up the reading.

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn! Worked perfectly. Here's another quick question if you don't mind; does pandas limit it's output and if so, how do I work around that? Thanks again!

Comment: @Matt: Not sure what you mean by that.  [The documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#console-display) describes some ways in which pandas shortens its output by default, and how to make it not do that.  If you have any more questions on this issue you should look through the documentation and/or post a new Stackoverflow question.

Comment: You should use `delim_whitespace=True` instead